# XSLT - Reorder comma separated string

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, xslt-2.0

I am hoping someone will be able to help. I have a comma separated string such as `A10,A12,A11,S10,S11,S12` This needs to be reordered to `S10,A10,S11,A11,S12,A12`

The ordering criterial is as follows,

- S before A everytime
- Years in increase order so 9 before 10 before 11 before 12 before 13 etc...

So for an input XML of:

```
<root>
    <row>A10,A12,A11,S10,S11,S12</row>
</root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<root>
    <row>S10,A10,S11,A11,S12,A12</row>
</root>
```

Comment: MMKD, The two requirements could be contradictory. For example, if we have `A9,A10,A12,A11,S10,S11,S12` and want the numeric part to be in increasing order in the result, then `A9` will come *before* any `Sn`. Please, explain what is the expected result in such case?

Comment: That is not a problem, as there is only one `9`. So as long as 9 is before 10, that is not a problem. The first sort should be on YEAR, so `9, 10, 11, 12` then the second sort should then be `S then N`. It may be easier for me to convert it....A9= "Autumn2009" and S10 = "Summer2010" that way you would expect A9 before S10 even though S should go before A, because of the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.0:

```
<xsl:perform-sort select="tokenize(row, ',')">
  <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(substring(., 2))"/>
  <xsl:sort select="substring(., 1, 1)" order="descending"/>
</xsl:perform-sort>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do note**:

The requirements in this question don't cover certain possible inputs and due to this the two current solutions -- by Michael Kay and this solution -- can produce different results.

The former produces a result which is always sorted numerically (and may violate the alternating `S`,`A` requirement.

This solution produces a result in which `S` and `A` always alternate in this order, but the numeric sorting requirement may not always be satisfied.

**Example1**:

```
A8,A10,A12,A11,S9,S10,S11,S12
```

**Michael Kay's solution produces**:

```
A8,S9,S10,A10,S11,A11,S12,A12
```

Here The "S always before A (alternating)" requirement isn't fulfilled

**The current solution produces**:

```
S9,A8,S10,A10,S11,A11,S12,A12
```

Here the alternation requirement is fulfilled, but the numeric-sorting requirement isn't.

---

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vTokens" select="tokenize(/*/row, ',')"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vASeq" as="xs:string*">
     <xsl:perform-sort select="$vTokens[starts-with(.,'A')]">
      <xsl:sort select="substring(.,2)" data-type="number"/>
     </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vSSeq" as="xs:string*">
     <xsl:perform-sort select="$vTokens[starts-with(.,'S')]">
      <xsl:sort select="substring(.,2)" data-type="number"/>
     </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <root>
      <row>
        <xsl:sequence select=
        "string-join(
                     (for $i in 1 to count($vSSeq)
                        return
                          ($vSSeq[$i], $vASeq[$i])
                      ),
                      ','
                           )
        "/>
      </row>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <row>A10,A12,A11,S10,S11,S12</row>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root>
   <row>S10,A10,S11,A11,S12,A12</row>
</root>
```